# Aframe : Stop Teleporting through objects

Tags: aframe

I'm using A-Frame Teleport component.
Is there a way to stop teleport from happening through objects?
(for example, when i point the controller to a wall, i can teleport through that wall!)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `collisionEntities` property from the teleport controls component. Example: `<a-entity teleport-controls="collisionEntities: .scenery"`. Then, add the "scenery" class to your ground AND your walls. By default, the raycaster will only allow teleporting onto objects within 45º of horizontal, so collision with the walls will block collisions with the floor.

Comment: Thank you so much Don. But it didn't work for me whatever i did. Now the teleport doesn't work at all!
Could you please check it: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tmp001 I did exactly as you said.